# CSP convert inline onclick event with passing a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, content-security-policy

I generate a list of applications from MYSQL using php
and then when you click on the relevant line it will open the application in a window,

something like:

```
<?php 

$Path = $ApplicationPath

print "<td class='centerTextIncPointer'><img src='../images/printicon.png'onclick='printTheWindow($Path)'/></td>\n";

?>
```

The above is blocked by CSP policy, how to I get the popup window with the application to work with CSP?

I tried to use the following example but could not figure out how to pass the path as my Javascript skills are not great and the list is generated dynamically.

```
<?php
    $Path = $ApplicationPath

    print "<td class='centerTextIncPointer'><img id='LineId' src='../images/printicon.png'/></td>\n";

  ?>
```

script.js:

```
   document.getElementById("LineId").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction(){

      // open the app in the window

    }
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
<img src='../images/printicon.png' data-path="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="return !window.open(this.getAttribute('data-path'), 'Google', 'width=500,height=500')"/>
```

Comment: This will still fail CSP compliance as its still inline code ?